# Search all the string type member in a class(including searching the property in class type) C#

Tags: c#, properties

I tried to find out all the "string" type properties from a class, but wonder how can I do that if there is any class type property in this class.

The following codes show the target class and my solution.

```
public class Credit_Card
{
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string billing_phone { get; set; }
    public Expiration expiration { get; set; }
}

public class Expiration
{
    public string month { get; set; }
}


class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Credit_Card).GetProperties())
        { 
            if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);              
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My "Main" method can only show "brand" and "billing_phone" properties in Credit_Card type, but missed "month" property in expiration class.

Is there any way that I can do recursive search in Credit_Card class?

Comment: Move your logic into a function and call it recursively.

Comment: The approach to take depends on what you want to do. "Print all property names" is nice and all, but most likely not your end goal. You'll want nested properties like `Foo.Bar.Baz` and properties of generic collections like `Foo.Bars[].Baz` too. There's also libraries that help with this. Explain what your goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
  foreach(PropertyInfo prop in GetStringProperties(typeof(Credit_Card)))
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);              
  Console.ReadLine();
}
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetStringProperties(Type type)
{
  return GetStringProperties (type, new HashSet<Type> ());
}
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetStringProperties(Type type, HashSet<Type> alreadySeen)
{
  foreach(var prop in type.GetProperties())
  {
    var propType = prop.PropertyType;
    if (propType == typeof(string))
      yield return prop;
    else if(alreadySeen.Add(propType))
      foreach(var indirectProp in GetStringProperties(propType, alreadySeen))
        yield return indirectProp;
  }
}
```

It's important to catch types we've already processed, or you can easily get into an infinite loop with the small mercy that since this takes a recursive approach it crashes with a `StackOverflowException` rather than just hanging forever like the iterative equivalent would. (Another case of the only thing worse than throwing an exception is no throwing an exception).

Comment: Incidentally, `Credit_Card` is an unusual name for a .NET type; `CreditCard` would be much more usual.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make a method that will recursively call itself, with the type to search as a parameter:

```
public void OutputStringProperties(Type type)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
    { 
        if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);              
        }
        else
        {
            OutputStringProperties(prop.PropertyType);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your initial call just invokes this with its starting point:

```
OutputStringProperties(typeof(Credit_Card));
```

However, bear in mind that **this will cause a stack overflow** if you have cyclic dependencies, unless you first modify it to keep track of which types it's already checked.